# trouble with using php classes in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, class

the error code:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'inc\woocommerce\Product' not found in D:\Program
> Files\Xampp\htdocs\aliahmad\wp-content\themes\aliahmad\taxonomy-product_cat.php:51
> Stack trace: #0 D:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\aliahmad\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106):
> include() #1 D:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\aliahmad\wp-blog-header.php(19):
> require_once('D:\Program File...') #2 D:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\aliahmad\index.php(17):
> require('D:\Program File...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\Program Files\Xampp\htdocs\aliahmad\wp-
> content\themes\aliahmad\taxonomy-product_cat.php on line 51

here is my php file implementation: (file: inc/woocommerce/Product.php)

```
class Product {

    protected $query;

    public $name;
    public $sku;
    public $price;


    public function __construct( $id ) {

        $this->query = wc_get_product( $id );

        $this->name          = $this->query->get_name();
        $this->sku           = $this->query->get_sku();
        $this->price         = $this->query->get_price();
    }

}
```

here is my making instance of the class: (file: taxonomy-product_cat.php)

```
global $product_query;

// use inc\woocommerce\Product;

foreach ( $product_query->posts as $product ) {

    new inc\woocommerce\Product( $product->id );
}
```

here is my files hierarchy:

```
inc
   |
    woocommerce
               | 
                Product.php

taxonomy-product_cat.php
```

every help appreciated

Comment: yes that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to make use of classes in other files:

need to include the file with **require** or **require_once** keyword after that using the namespace.